# Is there a way to set the font family of form inputs in localhost?

Tags: html, css, xampp, font-family

When using XAMPP localhost, I can't set the font family for form inputs.

The font is actually from Google Fonts, I already imported it in the HTML code:

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=IBM+Plex+Sans+Condensed:bold,medium,regular" rel="stylesheet" />`

Here is the CSS code:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
    font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans Condensed';
}

input {
    font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans Condensed';
}
```

When viewing as a file (not localhost), everything works as normal.
However, in XAMPP, the `input` tag shows the default font instead.

Comment: Did you try to add `!important` to the rule?

Comment: If you can see it normally without XAMPP, I think your issue has to do with the XAMPP setup and not the font, Chang. For some reason it's blocking port 80 or URLs in general. Could you please post the result or screenshot of the browser's console and the Network tab, so we can see if there is an error?

Comment: Generally speaking, always avoid using `!important` because it's kind of a last resort (or using a nuke to kill a fly). There is often a more precise way to do something, but there can be good reason too... https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, but you are fighting with browser 'preset' styles.

You could bring in [Normalize](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) or a [Reset](https://cssreset.com/) stylesheet into your project (or do it yourself), to allow yourself to more easily style your inputs.

Below is an example using an extract from Normalize for webkit engine browsers:

**CSS**

```
body {
  font-family: "IBM Plex Sans Condensed", sans-serif;
}

input {
  font-family: "IBM Plex Sans Condensed", sans-serif;
}

/**
 * Correct the inability to style clickable types in iOS and Safari.
https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/blob/master/normalize.css
 */
button,
[type="button"],
[type="reset"],
[type="submit"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none; /* or -webkit-appearance: button */
}

[type="text"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=IBM+Plex+Sans+Condensed:bold,medium,regular" rel="stylesheet" />

<form>
  <input type='text' value='Hello world'>
  <input type='submit' value='Send form'>
</form>
```